How to print PDF as 3 individual pages for poster?
Using Photopea I created a simple image intended to be printed across 3 A4 sheets and stuck together on a wall.
I started a new project in Photopea and set the size to 210x891mm (which is 3x landscape A4 pages side by side. I then rotated it because it came out as a vertical strip not horizontal. I did my editing then I rotated back to a vertical strip. I exported it as a pdf.
When I open it in Adobe Reader it looks like the below. I've selected Poster and no matter how I play around with the Tile Scale and overlap, it will not cut to 3 A4 pages. It tries to use 4 pages as shown, with whitespace at each end.
How can I get this to cut as only 3 pages?


Are your paper settings set to regular A4 or A4 Borderless? Seems like the sort of issue that would pop up if it was trying to deal with margins at the edges of each page, but this is just a shot in the dark.

If you click on Page Setup.. (at the bottom left) Acrobat will display the margins of the currently selected paper size. If you cannot choose or create a borderless page through the printer properties, your only possibility is to reduce the Tile Scale until you get 3 pages.

Thanks everyone...

When configuring Printing there tend to be rounding off errors. that flip a number of pages into needing one more. This is more common in browsers "print to PDF" but can also affect application printing and best to write a small test file to find the threshold so here I wrote a circle in Notepad and can see the distortions.
Note the page size under print dialog says 8.26 X 35.04 but the print says it will use 8.27 X 35.08 which is just able to fit inside 3 pages.
I could possibly tweak that a small amount to see at which part of a point it page breaks. but close enough since page permitted variation is nominally several mm anyway ! So much for ISO standard sheet sizes.

It also depends on the print application as here the page is larger, even for same printer driver.

However Adobe Acrobat will only use that size as 99% of true !!

Question
How can I get this to cut as only 3 pages?
Answer
Use another print application or set Acrobat Reader to 99% scale!
For 100% fit 3 pages then your source needs to be /MediaBox[0 0 595.0 2523.9]
In metric it will thus upsize to 210.0 X 891.0 mm if it is drawn as 209.9 X 890.4 Thus 3 pages as 2671 mm high!

